# Difference between equivalent and equal for c++20 three way comparison operator?

Tags: c++, c++20

In c++20 the new three way comparison operator <=> (spaceship operator) is introduced and it can result into four values given below :

1. std::strong_ordering::less
2. std::strong_ordering::equivalent
3. std::strong_ordering::equal
4. std::strong_ordering::greater

However when I run below code snippet it appears that both equal and equivalent are one and some thing, so I want to know what is the difference between them and in what scenario we should prefer one over another.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <compare>
int main()
{
    std::strong_ordering res = (2<=>2);
    if(res == std::strong_ordering::equivalent)
    {
        std::cout<<"Equivalent...."<<std::endl;
    }
    if(res == std::strong_ordering::equal)
    {
        std::cout<<"Equal"<<std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

O/P :

Equivalent....

Equal

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They *are* the same thing, both numerically and conceptually. If a comparison generates strong ordering between the items being compared, equivalence and equality are the same.

The reason there are two words for it is because this is *not* the same for other kinds of ordering. Weak and partial don't have equality at all; they only provide equivalence.

Equivalence means that two objects can compare equal. Equality implies something stronger; if they compare equal, [one can be substituted for the other in any const usage](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/cmp.categories#pre-4):

> the property that `f(a) == f(b)` is true whenever `a == b` is true, where `f` denotes a function that reads only comparison-salient state that is accessible via the argument's public const members.

If a type's comparison permits equality (which is a requirement of strong ordering), then it *also* permits equivalence. So for a strongly ordered comparison, they are the same.

Answer (score 5):

As [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/compare/strong_ordering) says, there is no difference between the two. Hovewer, `std::strong_ordering` is the only category that defines `equal`. All other categories only define `equivalent`.

Linguistically, `equivalent` means "considered to be equal according to a certain criteria, but may have irrevelant differences", while `equal` means "indistinguishable". Thus equality implies equivalence.

`std::strong_ordering::equal` (and `equivalent`) is normally used when a comparison takes into account all properties of an object:

> From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/compare/strong_ordering):
>
> implies substitutability: if a is equivalent to b, f(a) is also equivalent to f(b), where f denotes a function that reads only comparison-salient state that is accessible via the argument's public const members. In other words, equivalent values are indistinguishable.

While `std::{weak,partial}_ordering::equivalent` is intended to be used when different objects are *considered* to be the same, but may have irrevelant differences.

Answer (score 3):

Let's say we are discussing an ordering relation that we'll mark as `<`. Now, equivalence for objects `a` and `b` means that both `a < b` and `b < a` are false. I.e. neither "compares less than" the other. Equality would mean that they necessarily share the same value, rather than just not being ordered by the relation.

A classic example would be a case-insensitive string type. Where we want to compare the strings lexicographically without taking the case of the letters into account. So we will have for instance have that both `"aA" < "aa"` and `"aa" < "aA"` are false. The strings are equivalent under that ordering, but they are certainly not equal.

Answer (score 0):

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/EqualityComparable

> For the types that are both EqualityComparable and LessThanComparable, the C++ standard library makes a distinction between equality, which is the value of the expression a == b and equivalence, which is the value of the expression !(a < b) && !(b < a).